# How to remove shapefile polygon vertex marker points in QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, polygon-creation

I have created a shapefile layer and drawn a polygon to show the boundary of a woodland. How can I edit the polygon to remove the crosses that denote the intersection of two points on the boundary?

[image]

You can see that I have created a simple single polygon around the woodland area. I wish to get rid of the red crosses shown. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you attach image? These 'two points' - it is topological errors of intersetction polygons? For avoind intersection enable topological editing and enable 'Avoid intersection' for layer in Settings - Snapping options.

Comment: http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a525/benwells/BZN_test_zps2c1e27cf.png

Comment: You can see that I have created a simple single polygon around the woodland area. I wish to get rid of the red crosses shown. How do I do that?

Comment: On picture red markers - is vertex of polygon. Try Settings->Options-->Digitizing : change Marker style (Cross) to Semi transparent circle.

Answer (score 6):

On picture red markers - is vertex of polygon. Try Settings->Options-->Digitizing : change Marker style (Cross) to Semi transparent circle.

Comment: ... or leave Edit mode. This will also remove the vertex signs.